# for loop to create a column vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I would like to create a column vector with a function where one variable is fixed and one changes. I have the following code in MATLAB:

```
y3=ones(100,1)
for n=2:100
u3 = ((y3).^(1-n)-1)/(1-n);
end
```

where `u3` is the function. `y3` is a 100,1 vector and is constant. `n` is the changing variable. The output of my loop should be a column vector which shows in every row a changed `n` like this

> row 1 ((y3).^(1-2)-1)/(1-2);
>   row 2 ((y3).^(1-3)-1)/(1-3);
>   row 3 ((y3).^(1-4)-1)/(1-4);
>   ... and so on

The code doesnt work properly, please help me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There is no need to store `y3` as a constant array. If you know `y3` is a constant, just use `y3=1` and `(y3^(1-n)-1)/(1-n);`

2) During every execution of the loop, `u3` is being over-written. If you want to collect it, you might want to do something like `u3(n-1)=((y3).^(1-n)-1)/(1-n);`.

3) This can potentially be optimized by vectorizing the operation and getting rid of the `for` loop. Have you considered that?

Something along the lines of:

```
n = 2:100;
y3 = 1;
u3 = (y3.^(1-n)-1)./(1-n);
```

Comment: Thanks. Such an easy way.